# Engraving text into surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers, text-object

Hello fellow Blenderers,

I'm trying to recreate a seatbelt buckle for a car.
Like this:
[image: seatbelt]

But when it comes to creating the red button I'm having a hard time with engraving "PRESS" on it.
My approach is the usual one
Add text>give it extrusion> convert to mesh>join meshes>boolean intersect (knife)> delete unnecessary faces> Bevel edges, for support loops
And i still end up with this when I turn on subdivision surface?
[image: Overview]

[image: Sh!tshow]

Somehow a surface appears that covers the engraving ? cvan anyone explain to me what causes this ? and what a potential solution would be ?

[image: Without SubD turned on]
[image: Without SubD turned on here]

Comment: Hello, it will be complicated because the topology needs to be correct, you could simply fake it with a bump map instead

Comment: If not for 3D print, This looks an ideal candidate for a bump-map ..you're unlikely ever to see the profile.